# React and Contentful displaying a .map array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, contentful-api

I’ve mimicked a file for creating an array of items from the Contentful dashboard that was built by a previous developer, I’ve inserted the content into the page and added them to the graphQL section to ensure that it’s pulling in some sort of data but when I try and map the array it’s throwing an error as pictured below:

Error in function **createFiberFromTypeAndProps**

> **Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got `object`. Check the render method of** `ValueList`.

A couple of things I've looked at online mentioned importing the component via the `export default` method instead of exporting the function with curly brackets and either way this produces the same results for me. The code I've created is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import slugify from 'slugify'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Reveal from 'react-awesome-reveal'

import { BREAKPOINTS, ANIMATION, customReveal } from '../styles/cssVariables'
import Container from './layout/container'

const ValuesStyles = {
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  textAlign: 'center',
  overflow: 'hidden'
}

const ValueItem = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black'
}

const ValueList = (props) => {

return (
    <Container width={14}>
        {props.title}
        {props.valuesList.map((value, i) => (
            <ValueItem style={ValueItem} key={i}>{value}</ValueItem>
        ))}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ValueList
```

Have I missed something as I’ve tested that the component itself its passing props but whenever I try and map the array it throws a rendering error? Below is the code that's been added to the container page.

```
const valueList = get(this, 'props.data.contentfulPageContentStudio.valueList')


<ValueList title="Test Value List" valuesList={valueList}/>
```

Comment: Separately, [using an index as a key is generally not best practice](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) with an array whose contents can change.

Comment: Apologies for the missing < that's a copying error! Also I'm going to slugify the key once it's working correctly i was just using this to test.

Comment: The error is saying what's wrong. `<ValueType ...>...</ValueType>` is using `ValueType` as a component, but it isn't a component, it's a simple object (`const ValueItem = { backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black' }`). What are you expecting when you use it as a component?

Comment: LOL We've **all** made mistakes like that. :-) Happy coding!